# Cant add fields to ADO recordset - this operation is not allowed in this context

Tags: vba, oracle, ms-access, adodb

I need to add fields to an existing ADO recordset from an oracle server. This is my code I tried, but I get the error

> Operation not allowed in this context

```
With ADORec
Set .ActiveConnection = ADOConn
.Source = SQL
.LockType = adLockOptimistic
.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
.CursorLocation = adUseClient
.Open
End With
ADORec.AddNew
ADORec.Fields.Append "calcField", adInteger, , adFldUpdatable
```

SQL gets a list of IDs.

How can I achieve an extra column in my recordset where I can run a calculation within vba?

Or:
What would be your approach on this problem in the first place?

Comment: You can't just add a field to a recordset. If you want an alternate approach, start with _why_ you want to add a field. Do you want to alter a table, display a calculated result on a form, or something else entirely?

Comment: I want to do calculations based on a recordset. In the end, the data I got from the recordset and the value I calculated need to be displayed in a split form. That's why I tried to crumple all in one recordset, so that I can use all the existing fields in this recordset in my form.

Comment: Can't you add a dummy-field in you SQL-Statement? `Select ID, 0 as dummy from MyTable`

Comment: @FunThomas Not if you want to store data in the field. The dummy field won't be updateable and will only contain a static value.

Comment: This _might_ be possible, but I don't have access to SQL at the moment to test it.  If the connection is closed the recordset would then be disconnected.  So by opening it with a dummy field (@Fun Thomas) then disconnecting I think there might be a way of making it updateable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very rarely (= pretty much never) add fields to ADODB recordsets.

An ADODB recordset is, by default, bound to the table it came from, and making changes to it should make changes to that table. That's also clearly not your intent. While you can sever the connection or copy over the design and data to an unlinked recordset, that tends to lead to trouble.

Also, `.AddNew` refers to adding a new record, not a new field.

If you want to display calculated results in a form, do the calculation in the control source. Split forms allow for that.

Just add a control to contain the result of your caclulation, and set the control source equal to `=MyFunctionToDoCalculation(InpArguments)`

As a general rule, though, do the calculations in SQL if you can, both for performance and reliability reasons.

If you want to perform multi-row calculations (e.g. a moving average), comment and I'll share a substantially more complicated approach that also has more side-effects (such as errors when sorting/filtering/refreshing).

Comment: The idea to calculate the field on the go via a custom function worked just fine for me! Thanks